# How to query the metadata of indexes in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, schema, metadata

I need to be able to query a PostgreSQL database to obtain information about the indexes present and their details.

On SQL Server, I can do the following to get a list of all tables/indexes/columns for all indexes:

```
select TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME, NON_UNIQUE, COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_schema'
order by TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME, SEQ_IN_INDEX
```

It seems that the STATISTICS table of INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a SQL Server extension. How can I do the equivalent in PostgreSQL?

**EDIT: I'm specifically trying to return a denormalized result set as follows**

```
TableName, IndexName, UniqueFl, ColumnName
```

So I get a row back for each column in all indexes.

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is possible from the information_schema 
see [this discussion](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2009-04/msg00097.php). Indexes created other than from constraints won't be in the information schema.

However from the system tables you can 
see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204058/show-which-columns-an-index-is-on-in-postgresql)

Comment: Thanks - the linked question is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 7):

What metadata are you looking for?

There are all sorts of swell things you can find out, if you know what you're looking for.  For example, here's a dump of index stats and metadata.

```
SELECT *, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(indexrelname::text))
    FROM pg_stat_all_indexes 
    WHERE schemaname = 'public'
```

Digging through the postgresql wiki will turn up all sorts of good stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I've added an edit to show exactly what I want. It's more metadata than statistics.

Answer (score 2):

The query i'm using to see the list of indexes and it's actual size:

```
SELECT relname AS name, 
reltuples as count, (c.relpages *  (8192 /1024) / 1024 ) as size_mb,
c.relfilenode::regclass, cast(c.oid::regclass as TEXT), c.relnatts, c.relkind
FROM pg_class  c, pg_namespace n 
WHERE 
n.nspname ='MyNamespace' 
and n.oid = c.relnamespace
and c.relkind = 'i'
ORDER BY c.relpages DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not provide the “INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS” view.
But we can query some metadata like this:

```
select 
    t.relname as table_name,
    i.relname as index_name,
    m.amname as index_type,
    case ix.indisunique when 'f' then 'NO' else 'YES' end UNIQUENESS,
    case ix.indisprimary when 'f' then 'NO' else 'YES' end IS_PRIMARY,
    case ix.indisclustered when 'f' then 'NO' else 'YES' end IS_CLUSTERED,
    case ix.indisvalid when 'f' then 'NO' else 'YES' end IS_VALID,
    a.attname as column_name
from pg_namespace n,
    pg_am m,
    pg_class t,
    pg_class i,
    pg_index ix,
    pg_attribute a
where n.oid=t.relnamespace
    and m.oid=i.relam
    and t.oid = ix.indrelid
    and i.oid = ix.indexrelid
    and a.attrelid = t.oid
    and a.attnum = ANY(ix.indkey)
    and n.nspname=?
    and t.relkind = 'r'
    and t.relname=?
    and i.relname not in (select conname from pg_constraint)
order by t.relname, i.relname, a.attnum;
```

As Primary Key/Unique Key/Check/Exclusion constraints may generate an index by the default, so we should filter the system-generated indexes.

Answer (score -1):

Check these views in PostgreSQL about the stats:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html

Comment: Thanks, I've checked the first link and can't find what I need. I don't think the second is what I'm after.