# Does hasura generate indexes?

Tags: hasura

Hypothetically, given the gql query files, it could generate appropriate indexes itself, or just do so during the runtime. Searching the docs for index I got nothing.

Comment: So faunadb kind of generates the indexes along with graphql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasura does not automatically generate any indexes based on gql query files. You can verify this by querying the metadata in your Postgres instance; some helpful links to do that:

- https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-indexes/postgresql-list-indexes/
- [List columns with indexes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204058/list-columns-with-indexes-in-postgresql/42150886)

You can add indexes manually via a migration.

Related Github issue: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/2219